# Angular pdf.js preview and print

Tags: angularjs, pdf.js

I'm developing an app in AngularJs, which has to display a server generated pdf to the user.

Using pdf.js I successfully downloaded and displayed a pdf, the issue is that now I have to provide to the user a functionality to print it.

I see two ways:

- When the button is clicked, open a new window and re-download the pdf to show the print preview. But this'll overload the server;
- Download the pdf somewhere with angular, and let pdf.js only to render it, then to print use the previous approach only with a local file. But I don't know where save the file.

I'm missing something, there are other ways?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the PDF.js demo app - it includes a print button!

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: I've already seen it, but there are too many things in that file, I cannot make a sens out of it...

Answer (score 1):

There is an npm package which can do exactly this https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer

**Usage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <head>
        <title>Angular PDF.js demo</title>
        <script src="bower_components/pdf.js-viewer/pdf.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/pdf.js-viewer/viewer.css">

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-pdfjs-viewer/dist/angular-pdfjs-viewer.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>

        <style>
          html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
          .some-pdf-container { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="some-pdf-container">
            <pdfjs-viewer src="{{ pdf.src }}"></pdfjs-viewer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```